# Provide an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is not differentiable but $f^{2}$ is differentiable.

Tags: derivatives

A question on a practice exam asks:

Provide an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is not differentiable but $f^{2}$ is differentiable.

This confuses me because [$f$ is differentiable when $f^2$ is differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992711/f-is-differentiable-when-f2-is-differentiable) seems to prove that any differentiable $f^2$ means that f would be differentiable.

Comment: $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but $f(x)^2=x^2$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f:x\rightarrow |x|$ is a possible answer.

Comment: Note that the page you've shared says that is $f^2$ is differentiable at a point $\textit{and}$ doesn't vanish at this point then $f$ is also differentiable at that point. In the case of $f:x\rightarrow |x|$, the function is not differentiable at 0 and vanishes at the same point.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-1$ when $x$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity is needed as a premise.

Consider $f(0)=-1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\ne 0$ about its differentiability at zero.